# Average rows of variable length VBA

Tags: excel, sum, row, average, vba

I am trying to get a simple VBA code as part of a Macro that will put in column B the average of the values for each row.
I have code that generates a time series and fills a column per simulation such that each column is a time series starting at column C. 
The number of simulations vary so I simply need something that averages the value for each point in time (ie for each row across all simulations) whilst adjusting for the number of simulations that are run (columns that are filled). I would then like it to generate a single graph of all the time series highlighting the average values that are calculated.
Many thanks if you can help!

Here, for example, is the code that takes the values for the time steps from sheet1 and places it in columnA sheet2. I would like the macro to now place the average in the appropriate row down Column B:
[image: Screenshot Of current output]

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("E5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: You can use the AVERAGE formula. Example =AVERAGE(C1:AA1). AVERAGE will get the average of every cell in the range that has a value. So if you reference 10 cells, but only 2 have values, it will provide the average of the 2.

Comment: I agree with Daniel - why not just use the built in `AVERAGE` function. Can you add a screenprint of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I would like to incorporate this function as part of a Macro which generates these time series automatically. As I do not know how many columns there are going to be (maybe hundreds) and I may have to repeat the simulation many times it will need to be incorporated as part of this macro.I have updated the question and put in more detail as you request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B2:B" & lRow).Formula = _
        "=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(C2:E2)),"""",AVERAGE(C2:E2))"
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim ColNm As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ColNm = Split(.Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)

        .Range("B2:B" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(C2:" _
                                        & ColNm & _
                                        "2)),"""",AVERAGE(C2:" & _
                                        ColNm & "2))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth. Works well. Please see other comment.

Comment: One thing I would like to mention though. My code doesn't include error handling and it assumes that there will always be data in Col C onwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There will always be data after column C as I plan to run thousands of time series.**** I wonder if you have a code to automatically detect the data range on the worksheet so as to plot the graph? i.e replace the range part of the following code with something suitable? I see you have given advice to something similar in a previous post but I have been unable to adapt it to mine.   Sub Graph()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$E$101")
End Sub

Comment: Change `Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$E$101")` to `Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$" & ColNm & "$" & lRow)` I have already shown you how to calculate `ColNm` and `lRow` in the code above.

Comment: Brilliant. Works Great. I am indebted to you. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this although there will be lots of different variants on this code:

```
Sub AddAvgFormula()

With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[1]:RC[3])"
        .Range("B2").Copy
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Excel.xlPasteFormulas
End With

End Sub
```

At the end of your current code before the `End Sub` add this:

```
Call AddAvgFormula
```

Here's a varient of the original code:

```
Sub AddAvgFormula()

With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B2") = "=AVERAGE(C2:E2)"
        .Range("B2").Copy
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Excel.xlPasteFormulas
End With

End Sub
```

Another variant which is shorter but maybe not so intuitive:

```
Sub AddAvgFormula()

With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row) = "=AVERAGE(C2:E2)"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks very much. Both contributions really work well in calculating the averages for the example shown. However, the number of columns will vary so the average will need to be calculated from column C to "x" depending on the number of replicates the simulation generates. I am having trouble getting it to recognise how many columns there are that need to be averaged before doing the calculation that your codes to quite nicely. Any help on getting the graph to generate would be a great bonus too ;) ! Really appreciate your help on this. Thanks again!

Comment: will x vary for each row? or will x be the same for every row in the sheet? Maybe try just changing in the last variation `E2` to `Z2`...aslong as the other rows are empty then the `AVERAGE` function will ignore them.